# google appengine datastore client

Tags: python, google-app-engine, command-line, client

Is there a tool/client to view inside and make queries for google appengine datastore?

Comment: Ikai's website has a good tutorial on using the remote api for both GAEP and GAEJ.You can create .bat files and semi-automate most of your datastore dl/ul work.

Google's documentation follows


 http://ikaisays.com/2010/06/10/using-the-bulkloader-with-java-app-engine/
 http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html 
2 links. can't post as answer cause stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post every 3 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Starting with release 1.1.9 of the App Engine SDK, however, there's a new way to interact with the datastore, in the form of the remote_api module. This module allows remote access to the App Engine datastore, using the same APIs you know and love from writing App Engine Apps.

- http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api.html

And some wrapper around it:

> Today, I will share with you a simple script – remote.py – which can do all the necessary staging in order for us to talk with our App Engine back-end at Google. remote.py provides a single function attach(host), which will configure the API to communicate with the specified host. This will allow us to easily write scripts that interact with the live serving application, or if we need to, a newly-deployed version.

- http://blog.onideas.ws/remote_api.gae

Answer (score 1):

You can login at [AppSpot](https://appengine.google.com/) and go to the "Datastore Viewer". You can run custom GQL queries and view/edit entities in the datastore.

Comment: Can i have this "datastore viewer" for localhost?